# Use Subquery in FROM clause Hibernate HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

This is my HQL query, and it is throwing "**Invalid Token SELECT"**. How we can implement it, I read that Hibernate doesn't support Subquery in From Clause.

```
SELECT subQ.workItemId ,subQ.subject, subQ.workItemCrtdDt, subQ.workItemDueDt, subQ.workItemRcpntNm, subQ.workItemCrtrNm, subQ.lkWorkItemStatusCd,subQ.lkWorkItemPriorityCd 
                    FROM 
                    (SELECT WI FROM WorkItem WI, WorkItemRecipient WIR 
                      WHERE WI.workItemId = WIR.workItem.id and
                    (WI.workItemCreateUserId=:userId or 
                    (WIR.recipientId= :userId or (WIR.recipientId= :allUserId and WIR.recipientOrgId= :userOrgId)))) As subQ
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query could be simply rewritten to a regular select, you just need to resolve 
subQ to the correct alias.

Assuming:

table: WorkItem has the columns: workItemId , subject, workItemCrtdDt, workItemDueDt, workItemCrtrNm, lkWorkItemStatusCd, lkWorkItemPriorityCd

table: WorkItemRecipient has the columns: workItemRcpntNm

Then the query would be:

```
SELECT WI.workItemId ,WI.subject, WI.workItemCrtdDt, WI.workItemDueDt, WIR.workItemRcpntNm, WI.workItemCrtrNm, WI.lkWorkItemStatusCd,WI.lkWorkItemPriorityCd 
    FROM WorkItem WI, WorkItemRecipient WIR 
    WHERE WI.workItemId = WIR.workItem.id 
    and (WI.workItemCreateUserId=:userId or  WIR.recipientId= :userId or (WIR.recipientId= :allUserId and WIR.recipientOrgId= :userOrgId)))
```

No need for any sub-select in the From clause.